# Load only Javascript into webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to load a javascript code into Android webview, but nothing appear in webview.

The below code is what I have tried:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"<script type=\"text/javascript\" xml=\"space\"> window.location = \"https://d2cp7zapb031g5.cloudfront.net/app/faq.html\"</script>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

I searched much but can not found any solution that make it works. Can anybody have an idea to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether you declare internet permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

also, please add below code before webView.loadDataWithBaseURL:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Please do not ask me why

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. The above code has worked but can you please explain this for me? What does it affect in this case?